# Music Downloading Laws

Tags: music

Now, yes, I know, downloading music or duplicating CDs is illegal.

However, I overheard someone talking about the matter.

Assume I bought the album ABC with the songs A through Z from a store (i.e. I **don't** have digital copies like when you buy music CDs from Amazon). Then, I lose the CD.

Am I allowed to get the songs (and **only** the songs from the album ABC) from, say, YouTube and download them **if I can prove that I previously bought them (i.e. the receipt)?**

**Edit:** I'm living in Germany.

Comment: You should tell Apple and Amazon that. Millions of people are downloading music from their stores.

Comment: The very first sentence says that downloading music is illegal. Clearly this is false - there are businesses making billions of dollars by doing it - and artists becoming known by doing it.

Comment: Legal actions are legal and illegal actions are not, but that's not really a useful statement either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you buy the CD you have purchased a **license** to possess and use a copy of the songs that are on the CD so long as you actually have the CD.

This does not give you the right to permanently obtain a copy of those songs from any source you want, no matter what, regardless of what happens to your original copy of the songs.